# mongodb group by length of string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

Can you please help me convert this SQL query to MongoDB?

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(field), count(distinct field2), count(*) 
FROM table GROUP BY  CHAR_LENGTH(field)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Not yet there: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5319, so even though MongoDB knows the length it cannot actually give you it at the moment.

The best way currently it is keep the strlen in another field as an integer and then group on that.

Answer (score 2):

[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) is the current approach to this as there is no other present way to evaluate the length of a string and you need the JavaScript evaluation functions to do so:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit( this.field.length, { "field2": [this.field2], "count": 1 } );
    },
    function(key,values) {
        var reduced = { "field2": [], "count": 0 };

        values.forEach(function(value) {
            value.field2.forEach(function(field2) {
                if ( reduced.field2.indexOf(field2) == -1 )
                    reduced.field2.push(field2);
            });
            reduced.count += value.count;
        });

        return reduced;
    },
    {
        "finalize": function(key,value) {
            var output = { "field2count": 0, "count": value.count };

            value.field2.forEach(function(field2) {
                output.field2count += 1
            });

            return output;
        },
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

So since the standard JavaScript functions are available, you can get the length of a string in the "field" and emit that as the grouping key.

In order to get the "distinct" count on the other "field2" as well as the total count  within this grouping, the way the "value" portion is handled in both the "map" and "reduce" functions is important.

This is the part people often miss with mapReduce, as the "reducer" can in fact be called multiple times. So for example, if you are emitting 100 or more "keys" with the same value, then the "reducer" does not necessarily process them all at once. It may only call some of them, apply the reduce function, and then "re-queue" that returned document from the "reduce" for a further iteration against other "keys" of the same value or other "keys" that have previously been "reduced".

This is how large data is handled, and the reducer will keep doing this until there is only one value present for the same key. This is why the "signatures" of the "values" emitted needs to be the same in both the "mapper" and the "reducer".

Aside from "adding up" the occurances of the "string length" key, the "mapper" reduces down the "field2" array to just the distinct values by checking to see if that value is already present in the array.

This is where the "finalize" function comes in. As once the documents have been reduced, the "field2" value ( which is currently an array ) is converted to it's "lenght", thus returning the "distinct count".

It would be "nice" to have a "length" function available to the aggregation framework here, but as there presently isn't one this is where you use mapReduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $strLenBytes operator to group documents based on the length of a string.

Example:

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate(
[
 {$group: {_id: {$strLenBytes: "$columnName"}}, count: {$sum: 1} }
]
```